# DataTables get all the records not only visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables

I would like to get all the `records` from a `DataTable`. I have this `DataTable`

[image]

When I set

`"bServerSide": false,`

`"bDeferRender" : true`

I can get all the records(visible and no visible) but only in some DataTables.

Some other DataTables cant load to show the records like they crash with error

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`

My target is to add one button to get only visible records and one button to select all the records(visible and no visible)

How can I fix this ?

Comment: Take a look at **[DataTables: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24021259/datatables-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-length-of-undefined)** and **[DataTables Cannot read property 'length' of undefined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22470411/datatables-cannot-read-property-length-of-undefined)**.

Comment: xmmm yeah but it does not really work this. Not the problem I mention....

Comment: It's unclear how you're getting all rows now with 'Export to CSV' that leads to the error, please show your code.