# AJAX get boolean from asp.net webmethod

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I'm trying to get bool from a webmethod, but got xml string instead. Don't want to parse XML on client. 
In .net MVC i've achieved it simply by returnin' JSON, how to make the trick via WebForms?

The webmethod:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public bool MyService(string _container)
    {
       return true;
    }
```

The AJAX call:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/WebMethods.asmx/MyService',
        contenttype: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: { _container: JSON.stringify(params) },
        datatype: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
           if(data) {
              MakeStuff();
           }
        }
    });
```

What i've got:
`<boolean xmlns="%myWebmethodUrl%">true</boolean>`

Comment: Dupe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18244696/how-to-return-json-with-asp-net-jquery ?

Comment: @Vladimirs unfortunately, no.
[The solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18244696/how-to-return-json-with-asp-net-jquery) just changed type of XML from boolean to string. Not the way out.

Answer (score 0):

You may return response directly, like below

```
public void MyService(string _container)
{
   Context.Response.Write(true);
}


$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/WebMethods.asmx/MyService',
        contenttype: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: { _container: JSON.stringify(params) },
        datatype: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
        var BoolData = (data=="True") ? true : false;
           if(BoolData) {
              MakeStuff();
           }
        }
    });
```

Comment: My bad! It's a string! Not bool :( Not sure if it's good to parse string to bool

Comment: `Context.Response.Write(true)`
returns string type, when i expecting to get boolean :(

Comment: ok ok its consider as string means you have to convert it into bool